# Selenium (VBA) clicking based on Xpath which can change based on value on the cell

Tags: vba, selenium, xpath

I would like to click the specific button based on cell value..

Tried the way below but didn't work with error message.

```
bot.FindElementByXPath("//tbody/tr[&'sheet1.Range('E1').value' &]/td[10]/input[1]").Click
```

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Make the concatenation in VBA: `bot.FindElementByXPath("//tbody/tr[" & sheet1.Range('E1').value & "]/td[10]/input[1]").Click`

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! It's working so well.